# Safari: Wrong scrollbar color in scrollable div

Tags: html, css, safari, scrollbar

This is driving me crazy and I hope someone can shed some light on this!

I'm working on a website with a scrollable div. The website has a dark background so I want the scrollbars to be white. However, Safari makes the div's scrollbar black.

Here's a minimal example:

---

https://codepen.io/ruyven/pen/jOLvbQy

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="inner" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div.scrollable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120vh;
  background: #222;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.inner {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

---

In Chrome on macOS, everything is fine - both scrollbars are light to match the dark background. Safari however does this:

[image: Image showing the wrong scrollbar color in the div.]

View it on iOS or with always visible scrollbars, and it's even worse - both scrollbars are black.

Does anyone know a way to solve this? Preferably one that also works on iOS, which doesn't seem to support custom scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```css
html {
  color-scheme: dark;
}
```

I haven't dug too deep why certain browsers have issues with determining correct scrollbar color for elements with `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll`, when they have no problem with the default scrollbar used on the body element. But that seems to be the case nonetheless.

The above code will tell them what they already know: the website is dark.

Tested and this approach works in 2023, on Chrome & Safari.

Comment: Much cleaner solution, also works whether the scrollbars are set to always active or only on scroll! The only browser where it didn't work for me is iOS Safari, but that's most likely just a bug there, since it's supposed to be supported.

Comment: It looks like this bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216140

Answer (score 1):

Each browser has a different scrollbar design. In order to change it you can use webkit-scrollbar. There are some broswers that do not support this but Safari does.
This comes from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

Here is the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-scrollbar)

CSS:

```css
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvote because it works on Safari on Desktop, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work on iOS. Do you know if iOS requires something special? caniuse.com claims it should work. -- I updated the codepen: https://codepen.io/ruyven/pen/jOLvbQy

Comment: What version of iOS Safari are you using?

Comment: iOS 15. Both my iPhone and iOS Simulator are ignoring the custom scrollbar.

Comment: Ah, I just looked it up and found out that iOS dropped this in iOS 14+.. Sorry about that. I see if I can find something else

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if we can report errors on caniuse.com     
-- anyway, I did notice that codepen has custom scrollbars that actually work on iOS too. Best I can tell, they are using a completely custom JavaScript solution made for codemirror: https://codemirror.net/demo/simplescrollbars.html -- so maybe there's a version of that somewhere that works in a standard HTML website, or a React plugin would also solve my use-case.