# Scrollbar becomes invisible on IOS 15 safari inside flexbox with overflow: auto

Tags: html, css, ios, flexbox, safari

Edit: `overflow: auto` is enough to make the scrollbar invisible.
Edit 2: looks like a duplicate of [Safari: Wrong scrollbar color in scrollable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935669/safari-wrong-scrollbar-color-in-scrollable-div)

Why firefox on linux shows the scrollbar on the following text box, but Safari on IOS 15 does not? (removing `display: flex` or `overflow: auto` makes the scrollbar visible again).

How can I make it visible on IOS Safari too?

```css
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
overflow: auto;
```

```html
<p id="tbox">
  LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu odio sit amet elit molestie fringilla. Maecenas vitae nunc quis diam finibus laoreet sed sed justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Cras posuere arcu orci, ut fermentum lectus vehicula sed. Suspendisse potenti. Integer venenatis diam erat, in maximus mauris varius nec. Nunc eget ante urna. Quisque at ullamcorper tortor. Proin pharetra scelerisque ante, quis tempus tellus interdum
  eget. Duis eget tellus at tellus sagittis eleifend auctor ut dolor. Aenean eget sodales metus, nec luctus metus. Maecenas turpis lorem, condimentum in diam non, lobortis molestie nunc. Vivamus et lacus eu odio ultrices molestie. Etiam auctor pharetra
  fringilla. Nulla placerat ultricies risus, eget ultricies dolor volutpat vitae. Aliquam auctor suscipit eros et bibendum. Pellentesque lectus metus, dignissim vel sodales ut, dignissim et augue.
</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `height: 100%` or `flex-basis: 100%` to `#tbox`?

Comment: Just tried it - did not help

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple combinations and now I think I might find out why: mobile safari has a wried bug that it somehow doesn't change the scrollbar colour to a more distinctive one.

If you try to change the background colour to even a slightly different than white you can see the scrollbar.

```css
body {
background: black;
}
```

```css
body {
background: rgb(255,235,255);
}
```

Above are two example of tuning the background colour. However, (!!) if you use media query `@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)` and pass a light colour, it magically renders a scrollbar with dark colour! (See example [here](https://dev.yiximeta.com/web/stackoverflow/testcontainer.html), I tried to delete all other css styling that I used in this example but nothing changes.)
On the contrary, on macOS version of Safari, when the background is dark you can hardly see the scrollbar.

---------Edit Note---------

11-07-2022:
Sorry I did not notice that autocorrect change rgb to Rob.

12-07-2022:
Update the link for enhanced scrollability:

1. Change height of `#wrapper` from `200px` to `30vh`
2. Triplicate `p` element to achieve longer scrolling.

Comment: Thanks - so this bug only shows up with dark system theme. Still weird that it only happens with this specific layout as the scrollbar is visible normally in dark mode too.

Comment: However, I still can't get it to work with system dark mode and black-on-white text in the page.

Comment: Did you check my link? Does it display properly? I will do a minor change to make it better scrollable on mobile device but should not affect anything we are discussing here. My test devices are iPhone SE (2nd gen) and iPad Pro 11 (2020) on system `19F77`

Comment: I did check you link, thanks. Although it works, it uses dark background when system theme is dark, but I want black on white text in dark user theme too if possible. The scrollbar is styled only according to system theme, so `:root {color-scheme: light dark;}` also shows the scrollbar (but again, I need to always have black-on-white text).

Comment: I've updated that link to have also light colour background on dark theme. What I see is when dark theme is enabled, the scrollbar becomes white even the website retains a light background. So this is definitely a bug!